# Can I get proper IDispatch from DISPPARAMS?

Tags: c++, com, idispatch

I want to get a proper **IDispatch** pointer then cast it to **CMyDispatch** pointer and have my way with it later.

i.e. in javascript I want to do something like this:

```
var x = external.obj.x;
var y = external.obj.y;
external.obj.x = y;
```

where **x** and **y** are instances of **CMyDispatch**.

**CMyDispatch** is returned to javascript this way:

```
STDMETHODIMP CMyDispatch::Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID, LCID, WORD wFlags,
                                 DISPPARAMS* pDispParams, VARIANT* pVarResult,
                                 EXCEPINFO*, UINT*) {
  if( pVarResult )
  {
    CMyDispatch* pDisp = new CMyDispatch();
    CComVariant val( pDisp );
    val.Detach( pVarResult );
  }
  return S_OK;
}
```

In **CMyDispatch.Invoke()** with **DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT** flag I want to get **CMyDispatch** instance that holds **y** value.

When using the following code, **pDispatch** is set to some garbage:

```
STDMETHODIMP CMyDispatch::Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID, LCID, WORD wFlags,
                                 DISPPARAMS* pDispParams, VARIANT* pVarResult,
                                 EXCEPINFO*, UINT*) {
  ASSERT( pDispParams->cArgs == 1 );
  ASSERT( VT_DISPATCH == pDispParams->rgvarg[0].vt );
  IDispatch* pDisp = ( pDispParams->rgvarg[0].pdispVal ); // <-- garbage
  CMyDispatch* pDispatch = (CMyDispatch*) pDisp; // <-- garbage
  return S_OK;
}
```

What should I do to get proper **CMyDispatch** pointer?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't, downcasting from an interface to a concrete implementation is the first step on the road to doom.

That said, what you are doing should work, unless the javascript and the COM object run in different apartments, and you get a proxy passed to you, instead of the real object.

Why do you need to downcast?

Comment: i want to be able to set **external.obj.x** property to **y** object, that is **IDispatch** implementation.

Comment: and to do it, I have to get concrete implementation instance, interface is not enough, if I am correct.

Comment: I was able to get needed properties via this proxy pDisp->Invoke(). It's not answer to the question, but solves an issue that raised the question.

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a good, working solution. Glad it worked out!

Comment: Downcasting can break quickly with a simple windows update - there's a multitude of reasons why you don't see the actual implementation, but just a proxy.